# Changing the location for "Info.plist" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, info-plist

Before you say that this is a minor problem and was discussed a million times here and on other forums, I want to say that I went through all of them and tried to implement each of their solutions but with no luck. I either missed some very small detail or there is something wrong with my project in general. Hope you might help.

**The problem:**
After I've changed the location of "Info.plist" my project shows black screen.

Or I get the following errors:

[image]

**What I've already tried:**

1. In "Target membership" checked or unchecked the box with the project name
2. In "Targets" - "Build settings" - "Info.plist File" changed location to "Personal Quiz/Supporting files/Info.plist" plus tried all the other possible paths.
3. In "Targets" - "Build Phases" - "Copy Bundle Resources" - deleted and add "Info.plist
4. In File "Info" - "File Inspector" - "Location" changed to "Absolute path", "Relative to group", "Relative to project" and mirrored chosen path path to  "Build settings"
5. In simulation - "Device" - "Erase all content and settings"
6. "Command + Shift + K" to clean the project
7. Tried to read apple developers book
8. Tried to implement some code
9. Tried some other actions that I can't even recall

As a result I either have a black screen or errors above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It might be the occurrence of multiple **info.plist** files. So the solution is:

Go to your `Bundle settings` -> Open `Target` -> `Open Build Phases` > Expand `Copy Bundle Resources` and remove `info.plist` from there.

[image]

Now try to run your project. I hope it fixes your problem.

**Note**: Also check the path of your info.plist file

Copy the path by selecting `info.plist file` -> Goto `File Inspector` -> `Location:` select `Relative to project` -> And copy that path

[image]

Now go to your `Bundle settings` -> Open `Build Settings` -> `In Packaging` edit `Info.plist File` -> And paste the path which you copied earlier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried this before. It's points 2 and 3 in my "What I've already tried" list.

I tried this one more time just to make sure and there is still a black screen.

Comment: Update. Thank you again. I don't know what exactly helped but it started working  Your method helped

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the `Derived Data` already created and then `Clean build (CMD + Shift + K)`?

To delete the `derived data`, Goto Xcode Preference(CMD + ,) > Locations > DerivedData path

[image: XCode Preference > Location > DerivedData path]